# Mobile Push Personalization Options

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush

In the Mobile Push Personalization Options (see screenshot below), the system only offers a few standard options. However, I would like to know how I can populate this with my specific user fields. For example, in the contacts schema, I have a field called DeviceID. I would like send MobilePush using this.

But when I tried simply %%DeviceID%% it didn't work.

Is there a solution for this? Would an AMPScript be ok to use?

Thanks,

Shmuel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer posted https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/142044/16482 as it should give you the clues you need regarding DeviceID (or any other information in Contacts.